# Question about adjusting styling in moderncv package

Tags: moderncv

Still learning some aspects of LaTeX and I was wondering if you might be able to help out.  I want to use `moderncv` package for my CV, and I have a single use of my CV that requires everything (including headings) to be in non-bold text except for certain components to highlight.  How do I go about making sure the section headings and cvitem headings are not bolded unless I explicitly use `\textbf{}` command.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you! ... that answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you can do the following. If I did not understand you please make your question clearer, for example by adding an MWE reflecting your situation ...

Depending on the used style the definition for command `\cventry` can be different. The following MWE uses style `classic`.

Then the definition for command `\cventry` is

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

with three formatting informations `\bfseries`, `\slshape` and `\small`.

So simply create a new command `\mycventry` without these formatting commands like

```
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{% <==================================
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {#3}% % <================================================== \bfseries deleted
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {#4}}% <====================== \slshape deleted
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

With that command you can force bolded or emphased text as you need by the usual commands.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% <================================= changed code from moderncvbodyi.sty
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{% <==================================
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {#3}% % <================================================== \bfseries deleted
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {#4}}% <====================== \slshape deleted
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{really very long Institution--3}{very long City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}%
  {This is a very long description--6. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description}
\mycventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{Grade--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\mycventry{year--year}{Degree}{really very long Institution--3}{very long City--4}{Grade--5}%
  {This is a very long description--6. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description}
\mycventry{year--year}{\textbf{Degree}}{Institution--3}{City--4}{Grade--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\mycventry{year--year}{\textbf{Degree}}{really very long \emph{Institution}--3}{very long City--4}{Grade--5}%
  {This is a very long description--6. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description}

\end{document}
```

and its result:
[image]